# Azure Data Factory Slices

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

There are lots of demos online where slicing is carried out on blobs of the `myblobcontainer/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}` format or similar (i.e. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution/).

Now clearly this will allow for really easy slicing of the data as the parameters for year month and day have really clearly been defined.

What I have though, are files that more like this:

```
myblobcontainer/log_20151231_144229.csv
```

which is clearly `YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS`.

I want to process my files hourly, not re-process anything, and ideally not have to mess around too much restructuring my blobs.

Does anyone have any idea how I can "read" only these files that fall inside my hour slices?

Answer (score 1):

The folderPath in Blob Dataset can work as a path prefix. So you could set the folderPath like `"$$Text.Format('myblobcontainer/log_{0:yyyyMMdd}', WindowStart)"`, and all files satisfy the prefix will be copied.

Comment: i neglected to point out in my example that the "log_" prefix here actually changes depending on which server produced the logs :(

Comment: Sorry to know about it. Then you may have to leverage the custom activity to have your specific logic: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/. You can request it as a new feature and we will further triage it: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-azure-data-factory